# C++Builder keeps saying it can't find .LIB when build starts then tries to link with it - but the component was uninstalled?

Tags: c++builder

I tried a trial version of *Advanced Data Export* and *Advanced Data Import* for RAD Studio VCL from a third party.  I was having issues, like the one I have now, since they didn't provide a `.lib`.

I decided to uninstall it, and on the export uninstall Norton Anti-virus blocked deleting some files in the Embarcadero program folders.  The import uninstall went okay.  After the uninstall of export, it needed a reboot, so I rebooted manually, checked the Embarcadero program folders, and those files that were blocked from being deleted were gone.

Now everything is uninstalled, I can't find any traces in my `.hpp` or `.cpp` files, it doesn't show up in packages, yet every time I try to build I get a prompt about:

> Unable to find static library: QImport3RT.lib

then another for:

> Unable to find static library: QExport4RT.lib

I click Cancel on both, and it builds everything, but on linking it fails with:

> Fatal: Unable to open file QEXPORT4RT.LIB

Where the heck do I remove this reference?  It's not in the project anymore, and I can't find it anywhere.

---

**UPDATE:** I ticked the box to remove the reference instead of Cancel, and did another build, and that seemed to fix it, but I'd still like to know where the heck the reference was that I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference was probably stored in the .cbproj file. Whenever I get weird build issues like this, I search through the project file and usually find a reference to a .lib file that I'm no longer using.

When you clicked 'Remove the reference' this would have removed it from the project file...